# Adding Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search, hibernate-spatial

I'm working on a project in which I'm using Hibernate 5, which works well. Now, what I have to accomplish is to integrate Hibernate Search, so that I can look for objects by some of their String-type properties. By the way, I'm new to Hibernate Search.

The good news is that this project is really simple, as only two classes are contained within: ParadaWS and OperadorWS. These are the classes:

**ParadaWS** class:

```
    package model.paradasws;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Transient;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
    import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Analyze;
    import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
    import org.hibernate.search.annotations.FieldBridge;
    import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index;
    import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;
    import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Store;

    import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "paradas_ws")
    public class ParadaWS implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7772269835230124538L;
        @Transient
        private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ParadaWS.class);

        @Id
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "codigo_parada")
        private Integer codigoParada;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "descripcion_corta")
        private String descripcionCorta;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "descripcion_larga")
        private String descripcionLarga;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "codigo_municipio")
        private Integer codigoMunicipio;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "utmx")
        private Long utmX;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "utmy")
        private Long utmY;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name="punto")
        private Point punto;
        @Id
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinColumn(name = "operador")
        private OperadorWS operador;

        public ParadaWS(){

        }
        public ParadaWS(Integer codigoParada, String descripcionCorta, String descripcionLarga, Integer codigoMunicipio,
                Long utmX, Long utmY, Point punto, OperadorWS operador) {
            this.codigoParada = codigoParada;
            this.descripcionCorta = descripcionCorta;
            this.descripcionLarga = descripcionLarga;
            this.codigoMunicipio = codigoMunicipio;
            this.utmX = utmX;
            this.utmY = utmY;
            this.punto = punto;
            this.operador = operador;
        }
        public Integer getCodigoParada() {
            return codigoParada;
        }
        public void setCodigoParada(Integer codigoParada) {
            this.codigoParada = codigoParada;
        }
        public String getDescripcionCorta() {
            return descripcionCorta;
        }
        public void setDescripcionCorta(String descripcionCorta) {
            this.descripcionCorta = descripcionCorta;
        }
        public String getDescripcionLarga() {
            return descripcionLarga;
        }
        public void setDescripcionLarga(String descripcionLarga) {
            this.descripcionLarga = descripcionLarga;
        }
        public Integer getCodigoMunicipio() {
            return codigoMunicipio;
        }
        public void setCodigoMunicipio(Integer codigoMunicipio) {
            this.codigoMunicipio = codigoMunicipio;
        }
        public Long getUtmX() {
            return utmX;
        }
        public void setUtmX(Long utmX) {
            this.utmX = utmX;
        }
        public Long getUtmY() {
            return utmY;
        }
        public void setUtmY(Long utmY) {
            this.utmY = utmY;
        }
        public Point getPunto() {
            return punto;
        }
        public void setPunto(Point punto) {
            this.punto = punto;
        }
        public OperadorWS getOperador() {
            return operador;
        }
        public void setOperador(OperadorWS operador) {
            this.operador = operador;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((codigoMunicipio == null) ? 0 : codigoMunicipio.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((codigoParada == null) ? 0 : codigoParada.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((descripcionCorta == null) ? 0 : descripcionCorta.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((descripcionLarga == null) ? 0 : descripcionLarga.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((operador == null) ? 0 : operador.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((punto == null) ? 0 : punto.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((utmX == null) ? 0 : utmX.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((utmY == null) ? 0 : utmY.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!(obj instanceof ParadaWS)) {
                return false;
            }
            ParadaWS other = (ParadaWS) obj;
            if (codigoMunicipio == null) {
                if (other.codigoMunicipio != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!codigoMunicipio.equals(other.codigoMunicipio)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (codigoParada == null) {
                if (other.codigoParada != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!codigoParada.equals(other.codigoParada)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (descripcionCorta == null) {
                if (other.descripcionCorta != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!descripcionCorta.equals(other.descripcionCorta)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (descripcionLarga == null) {
                if (other.descripcionLarga != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!descripcionLarga.equals(other.descripcionLarga)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (operador == null) {
                if (other.operador != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!operador.equals(other.operador)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (punto == null) {
                if (other.punto != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!punto.equals(other.punto)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (utmX == null) {
                if (other.utmX != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!utmX.equals(other.utmX)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (utmY == null) {
                if (other.utmY != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!utmY.equals(other.utmY)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ParadaWS [codigoParada=" + codigoParada + ", descripcionCorta=" + descripcionCorta
                    + ", descripcionLarga=" + descripcionLarga + ", codigoMunicipio=" + codigoMunicipio + ", utmX=" + utmX
                    + ", utmY=" + utmY + ", punto=" + punto + ", operador=" + operador + "]";
        }

    }
```

**OperadorWS** class:

```
    package model.paradasws;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Transient;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
    import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Analyze;
    import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
    import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index;
    import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Store;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "operadores_ws")
    public class OperadorWS implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Transient
        private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(OperadorWS.class);

        /*
         Atributos
         */
        @Id
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "codigo_operador")
        private Integer codigoOperador;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "descripcion_corta")
        @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
        private String descripcionCorta;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "descripcion_larga")
        private String descripcionLarga;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "direccion_web")
        private String direccionWeb;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "telefono")
        private String telefono;

        /*
         Métodos
         */
        public OperadorWS(){

        }

        public OperadorWS(Logger logger, Integer codigoOperador, String descripcionCorta, String descripcionLarga,
                String direccionWeb, String telefono) {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.codigoOperador = codigoOperador;
            this.descripcionCorta = descripcionCorta;
            this.descripcionLarga = descripcionLarga;
            this.direccionWeb = direccionWeb;
            this.telefono = telefono;
        }

        public Logger getLogger() {
            return logger;
        }

        public void setLogger(Logger logger) {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public Integer getCodigoOperador() {
            return codigoOperador;
        }

        public void setCodigoOperador(Integer codigoOperador) {
            this.codigoOperador = codigoOperador;
        }

        public String getDescripcionCorta() {
            return descripcionCorta;
        }

        public void setDescripcionCorta(String descripcionCorta) {
            this.descripcionCorta = descripcionCorta;
        }

        public String getDescripcionLarga() {
            return descripcionLarga;
        }

        public void setDescripcionLarga(String descripcionLarga) {
            this.descripcionLarga = descripcionLarga;
        }

        public String getDireccionWeb() {
            return direccionWeb;
        }

        public void setDireccionWeb(String direccionWeb) {
            this.direccionWeb = direccionWeb;
        }

        public String getTelefono() {
            return telefono;
        }

        public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
            this.telefono = telefono;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((codigoOperador == null) ? 0 : codigoOperador.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((descripcionCorta == null) ? 0 : descripcionCorta.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((descripcionLarga == null) ? 0 : descripcionLarga.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((direccionWeb == null) ? 0 : direccionWeb.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((telefono == null) ? 0 : telefono.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!(obj instanceof OperadorWS)) {
                return false;
            }
            OperadorWS other = (OperadorWS) obj;
            if (codigoOperador == null) {
                if (other.codigoOperador != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!codigoOperador.equals(other.codigoOperador)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (descripcionCorta == null) {
                if (other.descripcionCorta != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!descripcionCorta.equals(other.descripcionCorta)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (descripcionLarga == null) {
                if (other.descripcionLarga != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!descripcionLarga.equals(other.descripcionLarga)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (direccionWeb == null) {
                if (other.direccionWeb != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!direccionWeb.equals(other.direccionWeb)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (telefono == null) {
                if (other.telefono != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!telefono.equals(other.telefono)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "OperadorWS [codigoOperador=" + codigoOperador 
                    + ", descripcionCorta=" + descripcionCorta
                    + ", descripcionLarga=" + descripcionLarga 
                    + ", direccionWeb=" + direccionWeb 
                    + ", telefono=" + telefono
                    + "]";
        }

    }
```

I must add these two lines to my configuration (I do it programmatically):

```
cfg.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider", "filesystem");
cfg.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "C:/Users/IN006/Desktop/paradas/indexLucene");
```

So here is the thing, I want to add Hibernate Search support to look for ParadaWS objects using their descripcionCorta and descripcionLarga attributes.

How do I configure this? I've been looking into the official documentation, and I need to add @Indexed annotation to ParadaWS class. Then, it's needed to add @Field annotation to every attribute you want to switch it searchable. Is that correct?

So these would be my modifications to add Hibernate Search support:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "paradas_ws")
    @Indexed
    public class ParadaWS implements Serializable {
        ...
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "descripcion_corta")
        @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
        private String descripcionCorta;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "descripcion_larga")
        @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
        private String descripcionLarga;
        ...
    }
```

Is that enough? Would I be able to search using this method?

```
    public void buscarSimilitudesNombreParada(String pNombreCorto){
        openCurrentSession();
        SearchFactory fact = getHibernateSearch();
        FullTextSession txtSession = getFullTextSession();
        QueryBuilder b = fact.buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(ParadaWS.class).get();

        Query query = b.keyword()
            .fuzzy()
                .withEditDistanceUpTo(1)
                .withPrefixLength(1)
            .onField("descripcionCorta")
            .matching(pNombreCorto)
            .createQuery();

        FullTextQuery txtQuery = txtSession.createFullTextQuery(query, ParadaWS.class);
        List resultados = txtQuery.list();
        for (Object obj : resultados) {
            if(obj instanceof ParadaWS){
                ParadaWS pws = (ParadaWS) obj;
                LogHelper.logDebug(logger, "Una parada tras hibernate search: " + pws.toString(), true);
            }

        }
    }
```

Later on, when I get used to Hibernate Search, I'd like to implement a search based on the Point object (Spatial features).

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: **SOLUTION** 
Finally, I came up with the solutions after several trials... ParadaWS class remains as follows:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "paradas_ws")
    @Indexed
    public class ParadaWS implements Serializable {
        ...
        @Id
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "codigo_parada")
        @DocumentId
        private Integer codigoParada;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "descripcion_corta")
        @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
        private String descripcionCorta;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "descripcion_larga")
        @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
        private String descripcionLarga;
        ...
        @Id
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinColumn(name = "operador")
        @FieldBridge(impl = OperadorWSBridge.class)
        private OperadorWS operador;
        ...
```

So, I have had the necessity of making a Bridge (I guess that this has been mandatory as I have a compound Id), so this is my OperadorWSBridge class:

```
    package model.paradasws;

    import org.hibernate.search.bridge.TwoWayStringBridge;

    public class OperadorWSBridge implements TwoWayStringBridge {

        @Override
        public String objectToString(Object pObject) {
            return ((OperadorWS) pObject).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public OperadorWS stringToObject(String pStringValue) {
            return OperadorWS.buildFromString(pStringValue);
        }

    }
```

And this is the buildFromString method from OperadorWS (what it does is to parse the String made using the toString() default method, so I post both):

```
    public static OperadorWS buildFromString(String pOperadorStr){
        String out = pOperadorStr;
        out = out.replace("OperadorWS [codigoOperador=", "");
        out = out.replace(", descripcionCorta=", ";");
        out = out.replace(", descripcionLarga=", ";");
        out = out.replace(", direccionWeb=", ";");
        out = out.replace(", telefono=", ";");
        out = out.replace("]", "");

        String[] strOut = out.split(";");

        OperadorWS act = new OperadorWS();
        act.setCodigoOperador(Integer.parseInt(strOut[0]));
        act.setDescripcionCorta(strOut[1]);
        act.setDescripcionLarga(strOut[2]);
        act.setDireccionWeb(strOut[3]);
        act.setTelefono(strOut[4]);

        return act;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OperadorWS [codigoOperador=" + codigoOperador 
                + ", descripcionCorta=" + descripcionCorta
                + ", descripcionLarga=" + descripcionLarga 
                + ", direccionWeb=" + direccionWeb 
                + ", telefono=" + telefono
                + "]";
    }
```

However, after all these modifications I wasn't, still, able to *fetch* data using Hibernate Search... Do you know why? My data is generated via another application (which runs on a daily basis), so it **isn't INDEXED**. It's quite a drawback, but a necessity to index all the data:

```
public void indexarParadas(){
    openCurrentSession();
    getHibernateSearch();
    FullTextSession txtSession = getFullTextSession();
    txtSession.getTransaction().begin();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<ParadaWS> paradas = txtSession.createQuery("from ParadaWS").list();
    for (ParadaWS paradaWS : paradas) {
        txtSession.index(paradaWS);
    }
    txtSession.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

After all tgis, I've been able to put Hibernate Search working.

Comment: Do you actually tried the above? Looks like you have all the pieces needed. If you have a concrete problem refine your question, otherwise just try first.

Comment: I'm going to update my question right now :)

Comment: Sure, you need to create and maintain the Lucene index. You can create it via FullTextSession.index, or maybe even better you could try the mass indexer. The recommended approach is to to then use the automatic indexing approach which will update the index as changes to the entities are made. This of course won't work, if external processes change the data. In this case you need to have a scheduled index update job. In this case it is helpful to be able to just select the changed entities (update time stamp!?) to avoid full re-indexing.

Comment: Btw, given the length of this question and the fact that it covers so many things, I recommend you close this question and open dedicated more specific questions in case you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for those comments @Hardy!

Comment: In addition to Hardys comment: Please never edit your question to add the solution to it, because that's what the "answer" part below is meant for.